# python - Pandas - Dataframe.set_index - how to keep the old index column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this `Dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Hugo' : {'age' : 21, 'weight' : 75},
                   'Bertram': {'age' : 45, 'weight' : 65},
                   'Donald' : {'age' : 75, 'weight' : 85}}).T
df.index.names = ['name']


         age  weight
name                
Bertram   45      65
Donald    75      85
Hugo      21      75
```

I want to change the index to the column `'age'`:

```
df.set_index('age', inplace=True)

     weight
age        
45       65
75       85
21       75
```

The old index-column name gets lost. Is there a way to change the index without losing the original index-column and getting the old column as 'normal' column again, so that it looks like this?

```
     name       weight
age        
45   Bertram    65
75   Donald     85
21   Hugo       75
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) first and then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().set_index('age')
print (df)
        name  weight
age                 
45   Bertram      65
75    Donald      85
21      Hugo      75
```

Answer (score 12):

Adding the `append=True` and with `reset_index`

```
df.set_index('age', append=True).reset_index(level=0)
Out[80]: 
        name  weight
age                 
45   Bertram      65
75    Donald      85
21      Hugo      75
```

Comment: This might be slightly more efficient than the accepted answer.

Comment: Nah, in this specific case at least it's twice as slow. I'm curious though, why do you think it might be faster?

Comment: this is slower in my testing

Answer (score 8):

Your DataFrame `df` has `name` (= `'Bertram', 'Donald', 'Hugo'`) as index

That is, your `df` is:

```
         age  weight
name                
Bertram   45      65
Donald    75      85
Hugo      21      75
```

You can convert the index (`name`) into a new column inside your DataFrame `df` by using the **`.reset_index()`** method.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

`name` becomes a column and the new index is the standard default integer index:

Your df looks like this now:

```
Out[1]:    
    name     age  weight

0   Bertram   45      65
1   Donald    75      85
2   Hugo      21      75
```

Now, you can change the index to `age` with the **`.set_index()`** method.

```
df.set_index('age',inplace=True)
```

`df`is now:

```
Out[2]: 
     name  weight
age                 
45   Bertram      65
75   Donald       85
21   Hugo         75
```

As **@jezrael** points out above you can do this in a single step, instead of two steps, like this:

```
df = df.reset_index().set_index('age')
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the drop variable to False.

```
df = df.set_index("age", drop=False)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: We need to use reset_index(level = 0). Your answer does not work

Comment: This doesn't keep the old index from being dropped, it keeps the column used as the new index from being dropped.

Answer (score -1):

The below is the most efficient since it appends the new index of `age` and makes sure its inplace

```
df.set_index('age',append=True,inplace=True)
```

Comment: We need to use reset_index(level = 0). Your answer does not work