# Pandas dataframe.set_index() deletes previous index and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I just came across a strange phenomenon with Pandas DataFrames, when setting index using DataFrame.set_index('some_index') the old column that was also an index is deleted! Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],'sale':[55, 40, 84, 31]})
df_mn=df.set_index('month')
>>> df_mn
       sale  year
month            
1        55  2012
4        40  2014
7        84  2013
10       31  2014
```

Now I change the index to year:

```
df_mn.set_index('year')
      sale
year      
2012    55
2014    40
2013    84
2014    31
```

.. and the month column was removed with the index. This is vary irritating because I just wanted to swap the DataFrame index.

Is there a way to not have the previous column that was an index from being deleted? Maybe through something like: DataFrame.set_index('new_index',delete_previous_index=False)

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Use `df_mn.reset_index()` first which will re-store the month column in the dataframe. Then use `set_index`.

Comment: Answers under this question: [python - Pandas - Dataframe.set_index - how to keep the old index column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720616/python-pandas-dataframe-set-index-how-to-keep-the-old-index-column) suggest using the argument `append=True` to `set_index()`.

Comment: @PaulRougieux Do you have any idea why df.set_index *sometimes* removes the existing index, but not always?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following

```
>>> df_mn.reset_index().set_index('year')
      month  sale
year             
2012      1    55
2014      4    40
2013      7    84
2014     10    31
```

Comment: This serves the purpose but the year is misplaced in the row. Any fix for that ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution I found to reatain a previous columns is to set drop=False
dataframe.set_index('some_column',drop=False). This is not the perfect answer but it works!

Comment: I think this prevents the `year` column from disappearing in the DF when you set_index(year). It doesn't restore `month` if it is already used as the index. Kay Wittig's answer is best - reset_index()

Comment: Actually, this would help the user a lot, if applied when you initially do `df.set_index("month", drop=False)`. This would prevent the month column from being lost, which would save 1 line in aspiring1's answer.

Answer (score 0):

> No, in such cases you have to save your previous column, like shown
>   below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],'sale':[55, 40, 84, 31]})
df_mn=df.set_index('month')
df_mn['month'] = df_mn.index #Save it as another column, and then run set_index with year column as value.
df_mn.set_index('year')
```

Besides you are using a duplicate dataframe df_mn , so the dataframe df remains unchanged you can use it again.
And also if you aren't setting the

> **inplace**   argument for set_index to **True**

df_mn won't have changed even after you call set_index() on it.

Also, like the other answer you can always use reset_index().

Comment: Apart from Kay's answer I am not sure what are you suggesting. Can you explain?

Comment: I just wanted to suggest that you can basically save your index column after doing set_index with inplace parameter true. But, the best method is using reset_index, besides just like I suggested, your df column isn't affected, so the month data isn't lost, after all.