# Using the original index after slicing a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe `dataset` as the following:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'id':list('123456'),
                       'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                        'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3]})
print(dataset)

  id  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  4  9
3  4  5  4
4  5  5  2
5  6  4  3
```

Now I slice it using `iloc()` and get

```
dataset = dataset.iloc[2:5]

  id  B  C
2  3  4  9
3  4  5  4
4  5  5  2
```

Now I set the `id` as the new index due to my needs in my project, so I do

```
dataset.set_index("id", inplace=True)
print(dataset)

    B  C
id      
3   4  9
4   5  4
5   5  2
```

I would like to select the new dataset using `iloc` on the original index. So if I do `dataset.iloc[3]` I would lke to see the first row. However, if I do that it throws me a `out of bound` error. If I do `dataset.iloc[0]` it gives me the first row.

Is there anyway I can preserve the original index? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - Pandas - Dataframe.set\_index - how to keep the old index column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720616/python-pandas-dataframe-set-index-how-to-keep-the-old-index-column)

Comment: You could access the first row with `dataset.loc[3]`. `iloc` works on integer indices (starting from 0), whereas `loc` works on the actual index and searches for an index that matches the one specified.

Comment: @AkhilJain For this particular example, yes. However for my real dataframe it doesn't, which is strange because I can't put my real project up here. I did check the link though. It's what I tried previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iloc` is slice by its position you can check subtract the lower

```
n = 2 # n is 2 since you slice 2:5
dataset.iloc[3-n-1]
Out[648]: 
B    4
C    9
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is recommended to use loc instead of iloc:

```
dataset.index = dataset.index.astype('int')
dataset.loc[3]
>>>
B    4
C    9
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```